# How does python threading run run its arguments?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, synchronization, python-multithreading

I have a python threading problem. I have been looking around for more than a day and it doesn't get any better, so I thought of asking for help. I use `python3.4`.
The first question is what would be the difference between:

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, url):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.url = url
    def run(self):
        spider (url)
```

and I'm using `toBeProcessed +'/robots.txt'` at some part in the code. If I used the above method, it doesn't give me errors -but it still doesn't work like it should, not all the threads does run. While if I used the below method it tells me it `unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_thread._local' and 'str'`:

```
def run(self):
    spider (self.url)
```

Note that I do have this declaration `toBeProcessed = threading.local()`.

The second question is about the rest of the code, only two threads do the work, the rest of the thread -whatever was their number doesn't work.

Full code:

```
def spider(url,superMaxPages):
    print(threading.current_thread())
    toBeProcessed = threading.local()
    data = threading.local()
    parser = threading.local()
    links = threading.local()
    lock = threading.Lock()
    writeLock = threading.Lock()

    # Start from the beginning of our collection of pages to visit:
    while 1:
        if LinkParser.numVisited > maxPages:
            print ('max pages reached')
            break

        lock.acquire()
        try:
            if not url:
                time.sleep(0.01)
                lock.release()
                continue
            print('to be processed ')
            toBeProcessed = url.pop()
        except:
            print('threading error')
        lock.release()
        # In case we are not allowed to read the page.
        rp = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
        rp.set_url(toBeProcessed +'/robots.txt')
        rp.read()
        if not(rp.can_fetch("*", toBeProcessed)):
            continue

        LinkParser.visited.append(toBeProcessed)

        LinkParser.numVisited += 1

        writeLock.acquire()
        try:
            f.write(toBeProcessed+'\n')
        finally:
            writeLock.release()

        try:
            parser = LinkParser()
            data, links = parser.getLinks(toBeProcessed)        
            # Add the pages that we visited to the end of our collection
            url = url + links
            print("One more page added from &i",threading.get_ident())
        except:
            print(" **Failed!**")

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, url, maxPages):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.maxPages = maxPages
        self.url = url
    def run(self):
        spider (self.url, maxPages)
```

not url is initialized like this `url = []` 
and this is how i run my threads, 
    `myThread( spider, (url,maxPages) ).start`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You need can't concatenate an instance of [`local`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#threading.local) with string. You need to store an attribute on your `local` instance like this:

```
import threading

toBeProcessed = threading.local()
toBeProcessed.url = url.pop()     
toBeProcessed.url += '/robots.txt'
```

Also you should consider to use [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) in your `__init__` method.

Comment: it gives me an error `toBeProcessed.url = url.pop()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pop'`

Comment: and what would it be different than if i use `run(self.url)` than `run(url)`?

Comment: in `self.url`, `url` is an instance variable. while in `run(url)`, url is just and argument to `run` that being said. What is the type of `url`?

Comment: its a list `url[]`

Comment: No it's not.  Perhaps you assign it a function somewhere in your code.

Comment: why would the `self.` change it to a function?, and is it suggested to use a `self.` to run the `run` ?